# Is it feasible to unpickle large amounts of data in a Python web app that needs to be scalable?

Tags: python, flask, scalability, binaryfiles

I am working on my first *web* application. I am doing it in Python with Flask, and I want to run a piece of Python code that takes an object, with Pickle, from a (binary) file of several MB which contains all the necessary data. I have been told that so using Pickle in a web app is not a good idea because of scalability; why?

Obviously, for a given purpose it's better to take just the necessary data. However, if I do this, with an Elasticsearch database and in the fastest way I can, the whole process takes about 100 times more time than if I take all the data at once from the binary; once the binary is unpickled, which will take at most one second, the computations are very fast, so I am wondering if I should use the binary file, and if so, how to do it in a scalable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is something I also have to deal with. In my case it's even worse, mine can be 100s of MB or more.

My first questions would be:

- Does the pickled data change and if so, where / by whom can it be changed?
- Are there multiple sets of this data that you need? (for me I have 1000s of them needed at different times by different people)
- How often is it needed?

The answers to those questions really raise different ways of approaching it.

Assuming you just have a big blob of stuff that's needed on a bunch of requests and is the same for everybody, and you know you'll need it soon enough - I'd load it either when the app starts and keep it in memory or lazy load it when first requested (and then keep it in memory).

The alternative approach is to split the heavy data bit into its own flask app.

```
# api.py: your api flask application
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

api_app = Flask(__name__)

big_gis_object = unpickle(...)

@api_app.route('/find_distance')
def find_distance():
    # grabbing the parameters for this request
    lat, lon = request.args['lat'], request.args['lon']

    # do your normal geo calculations here
    distance = big_gis_object.do_dist_calcs(lat, lon)

    # return the result as json to make things easy
    return jsonify(distance=distance)


# app.py: your main flask application
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template

main_app = Flask(__name__)

@main_app.route('/')
def homepage():
    # this is how you ask the geo api app to do something for you
    # note that we're using the requests library do make it easier
    # - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/
    resp = requests.get('http://url_to_flask_app/find_distance', params=dict(lat=1.5, lon=1.7))
    distance = resp.json()['distance']
    return render_template('homepage.html', distance)
```

How you then provision those will depend on the load / requirements. It's flexible though. You can have, say, 40 processes for your main front and just the 1 api process (though it will only be able to do one thing at a time). If you need more of the api processes just scale that till you have the right balance. The tradeoff is that the api processes need more memory.

Does that all make sense?

Comment: Hi @AidanKane, thank you! We would update the data to be unpickled from time to time, as once a month; it is geospatial data, public transport data... this kind of things, so is the same for everybody. By now it is just one file of about 10MB. So I just load it as a global variable?

Comment: In that case I probably would. The impact would be on memory. So, it depends on how many processes you'll be running (depends on load) as each would have a copy of the data. The alternative is to actually move the loaded data into a separate flask app with an api for the access. That way you could have as many of those memory hungry processes as required and have totally separate apps for the frontend side.

Comment: The global variable approach - or really, constant in your case so we can feel better about :-) - is so simple to implement that I'd start there. Without knowing about the load / access patterns and without profiling the code it's hard to say when you'd need to move on to the next (more complex) step after that.

Comment: The next thing to do would be to look at how you're accessing that geo data to see if it makes sense to put an api on it to access it. That's the "scalable" approach. Slightly more laterally, you might find that postgres with the gis extension allows you to get efficient querying while putting the data in a common location - though only you can know how well that would work.

Comment: The process thing may not have made much sense if this is your first web / flask app. When you run your flask app in production, you'll set how many processes it should have. Each process will serve one request at a time. If you need to serve 1000 concurrent requests you might be in a bit of trouble by having all the geo data in memory on each of them

Comment: But (thank you again @AidanKane) still in this last case an API for accessing the data could work well; then, if I have understood it well, the data would be in memory in that API and each process would take just the necessary things from it, right? Is it hard to make such an API? (I studied Physics, not computer science or engineering)

Comment: That's correct. It'll be no harder than making your other flask app :-) It's going to depend on the how the rest of your code needs to access the pickled geo data. First thing to figure out is which different functions you need to create to access the data. Let me put a little example in the answer.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pickle files is good way to load data in python. By the way consider using the C implementation: `cPickle`.

If you want to scale, using pickle files. Ideally you want to look for a partition key, that fits for your data and your project needs.

Let's say for example you have historical data, instead of having a single file with all historical data, you can create a pickle file per date.